# Cacti: Graph value returns 0 on SNMP Generic OID Template

Tags: graph, monitoring, snmp, oid, cacti

I can get the value from:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c desscrt% 192.168.120.39 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.7.3.1.13
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.311.1.7.3.1.13.0 = Counter32: 47
```

I try to generate graph with:

```
SNMP - Generic OID Template
```

with `OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.7.3.1.13`

But my graph display the value `"0"` it should be `47`,

how can I check to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In *Poller Specific Logging* enable MEDIUM or higher level of logging to log results. Then visit the log in System Utilities->View Cacti Log File, here you will see what the poller sees.